# Create customer using shopify api in application

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch, shopify, shopify-app

I'm developing an e-commerce application using `react-native`.

I'm stuck to create a customer using POST method and `/admin/customers.json` API.  When I call this API it gives me error that `Unexpected token '>'` in Postman.

I'm passing every parameter which is required but I failed to get output. Using GET method all registered customer's detail fetched but how to register using POST method in my application is an issue.

I also tried in PHP using cURL with (GET/POST) method it gives me proper result. But when I tried in AJAX both methods are not working and gives this error:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

I'm trying since four days but still getting this error. I asked in Shopify forum too but haven't got any answer.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: this is what I tried `https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/customers/customer#create` in postman first and there is no code I implemented yet.

Comment: It looks like an auth issue. Do you register an app and you are using the proper keys/secret?

Comment: yes I registered my app and used proper key/secret

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of this question. When I upgrade below versions. In this version git's pull request solved which can solve signin issue with shopify.

**Old Versions**

```
"dependencies": {
    "rect": 16.3.1,
    "react-native": 0.55.3
 },
 "devDependencies": {
     "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
     "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
     "jest": "22.4.3",
     "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
 }
```

**Updated Versions**

```
"dependencies": {
     "react": "16.4.1",
     "react-native": "0.56.0",
 },
"devDependencies": {
     "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
     "babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.2",
     "jest": "23.4.2",
     "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
 }
```